# Mordell's conjecture for curves over the field of algebraic numbers

Tags: number-theory, elliptic-curves, algebraic-curves, arithmetic-geometry, abelian-varieties

Is there a conjecture/result about the number of rational solutions of curves with genus ≥ 2 over the algebraic closure of **Q**? Is this set thought to be also finite as in Faltings's theorem over number fields?

Comment: A curve defined over the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}$ is actually defined over some number field, since the number of coefficients appearing in the defining equations is finite.

Comment: Are you asking about the set of $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$-points of a curve (of genus at least two)? This is always infinite (and dense). In fact, if $X$ is a variety over an algebraically closed field $k$, then $X(k)$ is dense in $X$.

Comment: @Ariyan Javanpeykar Sorry, i am missing something, I thought Faltings theorem says that *X(k)* is always finite, since those are *k*-rational points

Comment: If $k$ is a number field, then $X(k)$ is finite, assuming $X$ is a curve of genus at least two over $k$. But if $k$ is the algebraically closed field of algebraic numbers, then $X(k)$ is infinite (for any positive-dimensional variety $X$ over $k$).

Comment: Thanks @Ariyan Javanpeykar, but doesn't Hagen Knaf comment says that *X(k)* is finite even in the case of *k* being the algebraic closure of **Q**? since all solutions will live in some number field defined by the *k*-coefficients? I think I am confusing numbers, for example sqrt(2) is a *k*-rational number when *k* = algebraic closure of **Q**? Because sqrt(2) is rational as a member of the number field **Q** [sqrt(2)], right?

Comment: @Ponce: “ since all solutions will live in some number field defined by the k-coefficients”. That’s not true! Consider the equation of a hyperelliptic curve, eg $y^2=x^6-x-1$. This curve (ie the equation) is defined over $\mathbb{Q}$. But for any algebraic number $x$, there will be one or two solutions $(x,y)$, which will exist in a number field determined by $x$, which can be arbitrarily large!

Comment: Thanks @Aphelli, can you provide an example of two algebraic numbers and the different number fields determined by them for your hyperelliptic curve?